# Laplace Smoothing in Naive Bayes

Tags: probability, naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

[image]

I'm reading up on Laplace Smoothing/Add-1 Smoothing in Naive Bayes and I'm given the formula $ \frac{Count(Feature=Value) + α}{N + α\cdot k} $.

In reference to the image above, if we have to classify a new data point:

D15 (O=Overcast, T=Cool, H=High, W=Strong)

Then for P(No|Overcast, Cool, High, Strong)

we have, $\frac{5}{14} \cdot \frac{0}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{5}$

This results to 0

When applying Laplace Smoothing, what does ***k*** refer to? Because I've seen people refer to them as the number of features (Outlook, Temperature, Humidity, Wind) or the number of possible values (In the case of Outlook: Sunny, Overcast, Rain).

Do we use ***k*** = no of possible values of the feature:

$
\frac{5}{14} \cdot \frac{0 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot3} \cdot \frac{1 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot3} \cdot \frac{4 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot2} \cdot \frac{3 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot2}
$ = 0.004555

Or ***k*** = no of features:

$
\frac{5}{14} \cdot \frac{0 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot4} \cdot \frac{1 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot4} \cdot \frac{4 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot4} \cdot \frac{3 + 1}{5 + 1\cdot4}
$ = 0.002177

Lastly, do we usually check if conditional probability for a feature is 0 before applying Laplace Smoothing or do we just apply it from the start?